# SQL SELECT FROM with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I would like to make a SELECT FROM request, and instead of having the name of the column ( which is Alan), I would like to replace it by a variable ( which is the variable named pseudo), I know it can be done in php, but i am trying to do it in javascript using Node.js.

I have tried to replace the name og the column but the result in the console is wrong.

there are no error messages, but the data shown in the console is empty, it shows just an empty parenthesis.

```js
var pseudo = "Alan";
var onlinepeers = "Sarah";

var mysql = require('mysql');

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "espace_membre"
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  connection.query("SELECT ALan FROM matches WHERE Alan = '" + onlinepeers + "'", function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Don't munge query strings with parameter values.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 0):

You can try something Like this,Using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
var pseudo = "Alan";
    var onlinepeers = "Sarah";

    var mysql = require('mysql');

    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "", 
      database: "espace_membre"
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      connection.query(`SELECT Alan FROM matches WHERE ${pseudo}=${onlinepeers}`, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
    });
```

> Better Use Parametriezed Query

```
    let sql=`SELECT Alan FROM matches WHERE ${pseudo} =?`

    connection.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          connection.query(sql,[onlinepeers], function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
          });
        });
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, I tried to use the first sample but the console returns me the word "undefined" whith no further explanation. For the second sample code the console returns me "reference error: query is not defined", so i am making researches to resolve this last message from the console

Comment: Your column has `L` instead of `l` in the query please check for that,I have updated my answer it will be `sql` not `query`,Updated my answer pls check

Answer (score -1):

First create a queryString as follows:

```
let queryString = "SELECT " + pseudo + " FROM matches WHERE " + pseudo + " = .....
```

then:

Use the variable `queryString` in your `connection.query(queryString)`

Comment: thanks for your answer, I used your method but the result shown in the console is wrong, it shows the name of the column twice instead of the name of the column and the data ( onlinepeer) in it.

Comment: + SQL Injection vulnerability

Comment: Very bad form, since this is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: The query is being constructed on the server and the javascript code is running on the server. There is no user input, so this is not vulnerable to SQL injection.